# ESP32 NodeMCU Lua - How to control DHCP on WiFi Station?

Tags: lua, esp32, nodemcu

There is ipconfig for static address, but what about dhcp?
Problem is, if I already configured static address, how to select dhcp instead?
can I, at least, clear IP configuration somehow.
at the moment I'm on IDF4 build (IDF5 doesn't look any different).